# Is it possible to use electronic devices in the Room of Requirement?

Tags: harry-potter

Is it possible for the Room of Requirement to allow its user to use an electronic device such as a phone or a computer? I ask this because Hermione says that nothing electrical can be used in or near Hogwarts but this room seems outwith regular exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would guess not.**

When Hermione tells Harry and Ron that electricity and the like won't work in Hogwarts, she includes this reason:

> “All those substitutes for magic Muggles use – electricity, and computers and radar, and all those things – they all go haywire around Hogwarts, **there’s too much magic in the air.**”
>
> — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 28 (*The Madness of Mr Crouch*)

The Room of Requirement is brimming with magic, so if this really is the reason that electronic devices fail at Hogwarts, then you’d expect them still to fail.

Perhaps the Room of Requirement can create exclusion “bubbles” where magic can’t penetrate, which is the one way I could see this working – but there’s scant mention of it in the series, and you can imagine how useful it could be if you could actually make it work. Isolate your opponent in a duel, stop their wand working, then charm a rock to fly towards them.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the room isn't all powerful. As the members of the DA say in Deathly Hallows, it can't create food, so they have to maintain the connection to the Hog's Head. Based on that and other information about the Room of Requirement, my belief is that it would be able to accommodate the existence of items like that (so it could possibly even be a computer lab or something like that if the request was made of it), but it can't change the nature of the computer itself, nor can it manipulate factors outside of itself (Accessibility to phone towers, the internet, which exist far outside the room), so the devices would still be just as useless as they are outside the room.

Comment: Of course, we can do offline gaming...

Comment: Hermione learns from "Hogwarts: A History" that electronic devices don't work due to the "magic in the air." It just causes them to bug out. So like I said, I think that the Room of Requirement could create the devices and plop them in there, but they wouldn't actually do anything.